# I am trying to write a program for Armstrong number in PL/SQL.Can anyone tell me where i am wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

```
while  N !=0
LOOP

R:=MOD(N,10);
R1:=power(R,3);
A:=A+R1;
N:=TRUNC(N/10);

END LOOP;
```

After this it comes IF N=A THEN
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' number is armstrong ');
ELSE
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' number is  not an armstrong ');

Comment: Show the whole code block, what you expect to see, and what you actually see. A definition of an Armstrong number, or at least a link to one, might be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when you compare (N=A) because N is zero at the end of LOOP. Then you must compare A with the original number entered, (NOrig=A). 
This procedure you can help:

```
create or replace procedure amstrong_number(pNumber int)
is

  NOrig int:=0;
  N int:=0;
  R int:=0;
  R1 int:=0;
  A int:=0;

begin

  NOrig:=pNumber;
  N:=pNumber;

  WHILE N!= 0
  LOOP

    R:=MOD(N,10);
    R1:=POWER(R,3);
    A:=A+R1;
    N:=TRUNC(N/10);

  END LOOP;

  IF NOrig = A THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(' number is amstrong ');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line(' number is not an amstrong ');
  END IF;

end;
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you :) is procedure the only way ? Is doing it simply possible ?

Comment: Why do you need NOrig? You can simply compare to pNumber!

Comment: For good practices, I put the parameters in internal variables.

Comment: Sean, you can use procedure, function or anoymous block depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say you want to take user input from the keyboard. It is not clear how you plan to do that; in general, PL/SQL does not have facilities for interaction with end users, it is a language for processing on the server.

One way to have the user provide a number is to have a procedure with an in parameter. Below is one example of how you can do it. You must compile the procedure first (for example, I saved it in a script, "Armstrong.sql", and then I ran the command "start Armstrong" in SQL*Plus). Then the user can use the procedure, which I called is_Armstrong, from SQL*Plus or a graphical interface like SQL Developer or Toad, like this:  exec is_Armstrong(...)  where in parentheses is the user's input number.

I built in two application exception checks - for negative or non-integer numbers and for numbers that are too long (more than 20 digits). I wrote it for Armstrong numbers of arbitrary length (<= 20), limiting it to three digits doesn't save almost any work so why not make it general. There are other possible application exceptions - for example, what if the user inputs a string instead of a number? I didn't handle all the errors - the very last example below shows an unhandled one. Write your own error handling code for whatever else you want to handle explicitly.

**Content of Armstrong.sql:**

```
create or replace procedure is_Armstrong(p_input_number number)
as
   l_string varchar2(20);
   l_sum number := 0;
   l_loop_counter number;
   l_len number;
   not_a_positive_integer exception;
   number_too_large exception;
begin
   l_string := to_char(p_input_number); 
   l_len    := length(l_string);    
   if p_input_number <= 0 or p_input_number != floor(p_input_number) then
      raise not_a_positive_integer;
   elsif l_len > 20 then
      raise number_too_large;
   end if;
   for l_loop_counter in 1..l_len
   loop
      l_sum := l_sum + power(to_number(substr(l_string, l_loop_counter, 1)), l_len);
   end loop;
   if p_input_number = l_sum then
      dbms_output.put_line('Number ' || l_string || ' is an Armstrong number.');
   else 
      dbms_output.put_line('Number ' || l_string || ' is not an Armstrong number.');
   end if;
exception
   when not_a_positive_integer then
      dbms_output.put_line('Input number must be a positive integer.');
   when number_too_large then
      dbms_output.put_line('Input number must be no more than twenty digits.');
end;
/
```

**Compiling the procedure:**

```
SQL> start Armstrong.sql
Procedure created.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

**Usage examples:**

```
SQL> exec is_Armstrong(-33);
Input number must be a positive integer
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.08

SQL> exec is_Armstrong(1.5);
Input number must be a positive integer
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.08

SQL> exec is_Armstrong(1234512345123451234512345);
Input number must be no more than twenty digits
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

SQL> exec is_Armstrong(3);
Number 3 is an Armstrong number.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> exec is_Armstrong(100);
Number 100 is not an Armstrong number.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> exec is_Armstrong(371);
Number 371 is an Armstrong number.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> exec is_Armstrong('abc')
BEGIN is_Armstrong('abc'); END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) actually I'm new to plsql  so i didn't know that we have to use procedure so plz can you tell me in which cases we've to use procedure ?

Comment: What you showed us was the body of a procedure; you didn't have the key lines ("create procedure", "begin", "end") but you did have the code that goes into the procedure (incomplete and not exactly right, but that's not the point). In general you write PL/SQL to create functions and procedures - you can't just say "n = 3, n = n+5, print n" - there is no such thing, it MUST be in a procedure or function. You choose function when you need to return ONE VALUE as the value of the function. In all other cases you use procedure.